# TimelineLite (TweenMax) Not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, gsap

I used GreenSock-TweenMax write a mask animation  which is working fine in Firefox and Safari. However, there is no animation effects in Chrome, ( the code is actually working ) I couldn't figure out why.

```js
var n = 200;
function buildShield(s) {
    var timeline = new TimelineLite();
     n = n+s;
  var to = {
    y: n,
//    ease: Linear.easeOut
  };
  var duration = 2;
    timeline.to("#curtain", duration, to, 1);
}


function increase(n){
 buildShield(-40);
}


function decrease(){
 buildShield(20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="mark-shield" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="286px" height="311px" viewBox="0 0 286 311" enable-background="new 0 0 286 311" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
  <mask id="mask">
   <polygon fill="white" points="143.705,32.138 262.554,73.118 243.826,227.782 143.705,282.861 44.218,228.222 25.821,73.889 "/>
  </mask>
  <g id="curtain" style="transform:translateY(260px);">
 <rect id="cr-left" x="9.875" y="28.999" fill="#41B3A1" width="134.312" height="263.573"/>
 <rect id="cr-right"x="144.188" y="28.999" fill="#269D8A" width="138.479" height="263.573"/>
 </g>
 </defs>
<polygon fill="#D7D5D3" stroke="#A9A7A5" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="143.641,15.249 278.5,61.75 
 257.25,237.25 143.641,299.75 30.75,237.75 9.875,62.625 "/>
 <polygon fill="#c9c9c9" points="143.705,32.138 143.705,282.861 243.826,227.782 262.554,73.118 "/>
 <use mask="url(#mask)" xlink:href="#curtain"/>
</svg>
<div id="btn-in" onClick="increase(100)" style="background: grey; cursor:pointer;">increase 100</div>
<div id="btn-de" onClick="decrease()" style="background: grey; cursor:pointer; margin-top:10px;">decrease 60</div>
```

Comment: Why not report this to GreenSock?

Comment: I have a similar problem too. My animations worked just well until I upgraded my chrome version. Kindly post your findings here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your trying to animate `#curtain` which is an SVG graphical element, that is within a SVG `<defs>` element.

`<defs>` elements are not directly rendered with CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs

> **Graphical elements defined in a defs will not be directly rendered.** You can use a  element to render those elements wherever you want on the viewport.

GSAP uses the [CSSPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/) by default, but since your targeting an element within the SVG `<defs>` element you must use the [GSAP AttrPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/AttrPlugin/).

So you have to animate the attributes directly, wrapping those attributes with an `attr:{}` to show you intend too animate attributes.

Wrap `y` in `attr:{}`

```
var n = 200;
function buildShield(s) {
    var timeline = new TimelineLite();
    n = n+s;
    var to = {
       attr: {y: n}, // wrap y in attr:{}
    };
    var duration = 2;
    timeline.to("#curtain", duration, to, 1);
 }

 function increase(n){
    buildShield(-40);
 }

 function decrease(){
    buildShield(20);
 }
```